# How can I delete flash messages once a page has loaded using express?

Tags: node.js, express

So I was using express.js under node.js and came across this question. I have a login page where if you get a password/username wrong it will flash a message (Basic stuff using passport). But if you keep trying, the other error messages will stack (Only 1 of each, but they're still there after they're not relevant).

Is there a way i can delete the flash messages once they've been displayed? I'm using [this flash](https://github.com/expressjs/flash/).

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
router.get("/login", function(req, res){
  res.render("login");
  res.locals.flash = [];  
});
```

and my post req

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate(
  "local",
  {
    successRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: true
  }
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the `connect-flash` package, with this one you can do smtg like this :

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res){
  // if credentials are wrong
  req.flash('msg', 'Try again !')
  res.redirect('/login');
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login', { message : req.flash('msg') });
});
```

In the views, you just need to check for **message** existence and output it , with **ejs** it would be smtg like this :

```
<% if(message){ %> 
  <%= message %>
<% } %>
```

[package:connect-flash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash)

Comment: Are the flashes persistent?

Comment: No, that's why you i suggested them, they're only outputing the first time, once you refresh the page, they're gone.

Comment: Here's how I did it in handlebars.

        {{#if flash}}
            <a href="#" class="alert alert-danger">
            {{flash}}
            </a>
            <hr />
        {{/if}}


        res.render("login", {flash: req.flash("error")});